# SSIS step needed to count number of rows and error if zero

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to check if a table has been populated before proceeding in an SSIS package (SQL2008 R2).

My thoughts were to add an Execute SQL task, and use a CASE statement, but it's not the correct format.

```
CASE
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STAGING.dbo.tableX) <1
    THEN RaisError('NO ROWS',18,1)
ELSE 
END AS X
```

This should be easy, but I am stymied.
Thanks

Comment: Use an execute SQL Task to select count(*) from the table and if the result is 0 then you can set the condition on a precedence constraint. Simple enough.

Comment: To raise an error this way, you would want to use IF instead of CASE.  @rvphx makes a pretty good suggestion.

Comment: @rvphx Can you elaborate on how to accomplish this in the Execute SQL Task?  I understand the Precedence Constraint, but not how to set the condition if 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a variable of type INT

2) On the Execute SQL Task, set the result set to "Single Row".

3) Go To Result Set tab on Execute SQL Task and refer to the variable you created on step 1

4) Set the result Name as "0".

5) Configure the precedence constraint as @VariableName > 1 (This will let the package go to the next step when the row count is > 1

You can change the condition on step 5 to do what you want with the package. This was just an example.

Comment: @rvphx I want to check the data count is 0 and prevent the further job execution, i have linked the OLE DB source to Excel destination. Since it is data flow process I couldn't include the Exe SQL Task block. Do we have an alternate option for this?